# android cursor adapter display wrong data in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

I have an app utilizing Action Bar with Tab navigation which displays a listview via custom cursor adapter and then displays detail data when a listview item is clicked.  It all works well when my device is in portrait orientation.

My problem arises when my device is in landscape orientation.  When I click on an item, the detail view displays the item at the top of the visible list.  ie: items Accolate - Actonel are visible in the list. No matter which item I click on, Accolate is displayed.

Screenshot:

[image: landscape screenshot]

Here is my onListItemClick method:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
mCurCheckPosition = position;
items.setSelectedPosition(position, cursor);
}
```

I'm using fragments for my listview and detailview.  The only difference from portrait to landscape is I'm connecting to a frame in landscape mode.  Here is my adapter code:

```
    public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout , cursor, from, to);
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int position, Cursor cursor) {

        // create data array
        String [] data = new String[] { 
                cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getString(6), 
                cursor.getString(7),
                cursor.getString(8), 
                cursor.getString(9), 
                cursor.getString(10),
                cursor.getString(4)
        };

        // create the detail fragment
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (mDualPane == false) {
            DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
            bundle.putStringArray("Data", data);
            detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, detailFragment);   
            ft.addToBackStack(null);           
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
            bundle.putStringArray("Data", data);
            detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.replace(R.id.details, detailFragment);           
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 
            ft.commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        // create the title textview
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        title.setText(cursor.getString(4));

    }
}
```

I have logged the position during the click and it matches the correct record in my cursor, yet the adapter is displaying the wrong data.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.  thanks in advanced.

Comment: do you have xml layouts defined for both orientations ?

Comment: Yes, I have xml layouts for both orientations and they are working well as I do have a dual pane with listview on left and detail on right.  The main issue is in landscape, the wrong data is being displayed.

Comment: the *data* is different across views ?? that makes me suspicious of the fragments. What happens if you pull them out and just set them up as test activities, stand alone - the problem one using its xml layout ?

Comment: I can force it to be in "landscape mode" all of the time and see if I get the same behavior when it is in portrait.  I thinks its an issue with my adapter though.

Comment: does your OP contain all the adapter code ?? It looks like its missing some stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was causing my problem.  I had the following command in my ListFragment:

```
 getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

I thought it had to do with tagging lines in a listview